# In Robot Framework, How Can I change the value of my variable it it's not a number

Tags: robotframework

In Robot Framework, How Can I change the value of my variable it it's not a number.

I need help as it is resulting to an error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GhHsX.png)

${deliveryfee} =  Get Text     xpath://*[@class='open-page auto-expand-transition']//*[@class='summary-row'][2]//*[@class='price total']

Run Keyword If    ${deliveryfee} == "-"  ${deliveryfee} =  Replace String     -       0.00
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NmYsI.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things: You need to have `${deliveryfee}` in double quotes, and your code would look better if you used the new IF - END style:

```
${deliveryfee}=    Set Variable    -
IF    "${deliveryfee}" == "-"
     ${deliveryfee}=    Replace String     ${deliveryfee}    -     0.00
END
```